# Search Function for a Non-Binary Tree C++

Tags: c++, string, function, search, tree

I have written a search by string function for a non-binary tree. I know my function isn't correct in its current form and I could use some help fixing it up. The function returns a node pointer and it's a recursive function. Elem is a typedef string and subtree is a inputted node pointer. Also each node in the tree has a vector of node pointers called "child". That is what child.size() is referring to.

```
Node* AnimalTree::searchNodeString(const Elem& val, Node* subtree)
{

    if (subtree->value == val || subtree->child.size() == 0)
    {
        return subtree;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < subtree->value.size(); ++i)
        {
            subtree = subtree->child[i];
            searchNodeString(val, subtree);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write a search function for a binary tree?

Comment: Your compiler should warn you about the missing return.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly common mistake with recursion:  You need to return or process something with the return value of the recursive call.  In your case, that's the call to `searchNodeString` in your `i` loop.  At that point you need to determine if you're done recursing (and can return right away), or you need to keep searching thru your values.

How do you handle not finding your `val`?

Also, your recursive call is wrong.  You don't want to change the value of `subtree` in your `i` loop (or anywhere else in the function).

Comment: The `subtree = subtree->child[i];` part also makes no sense.